# Importing matlab structs within structs in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, python-import, matlab-struct

I have MATLAB data files which contain multiple structs within struct that i want to import into python. In MATLAB, if `main_struct` is the main file, I can get down to the data I need by -

```
leaf1 = main_struct.tree1.leaf1

leaf2 = main_struct.tree1.leaf2
```

and so on. Now I want to import the .mat file containing struct in python and access `leaf1` and `leaf2`. In python, I can load the mat files -

```
import scipy.io as sio

data = sio.loadmat("main_struct.mat",squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False);
tree1 = data.['tree1'];
```

How do I access the second struct in `tree1` ?

Comment: a couple of handy functions in python are `type()` - which tells you what kind of object you have (dict, list, etc.) and `dir()` - which shows you the attributes, both built-in and user-defined.  These two functions can help you "explore" an imported object and figure out exactly how to dereference it.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `tree = data['tree1']` (no dot between `data` and `[`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in MATLAB you have the following

```
S = struct('tree1', struct('leaf1', {1}, 'leaf2', {2}));
save('filename.mat', '-struct', 'S')
```

If you use `loadmat` with `struct_as_record = False`, the result of `data['tree1']` is a `scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct` object which can be used to access the nested structures.

You access the underlying data in the following way:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

data = loadmat('filename.mat', squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)

leaf1 = data['tree1'].leaf1
# 1

leaf2 = data['tree1'].leaf2
# 2
```